# How to convert a java project to a plugin project in Ant?

Tags: java, eclipse, jenkins, ant, eclipse-plugin

I am currently trying to write a `build.xml` which will convert a normal java project say `com.example.normal` to `com.example.plugin.jar`.

I have the code for a basic build.xml which creates a jar of the source project. But normally creating a `jar` file is not the same as creating a plugin jar file. For this reason I need to create a `plugin jar` file using ant and not just a normal jar file which cannot act as a plugin.

This is the example code snippet for creating the jar file.

```
<jar destfile="generatedPlugins/com.example.normal.jar">
       <fileset dir="JavaSource/com.example.normal"/>
</jar>
```

**Manually**, I can create a plugin with the following steps:

> Right Click on project > `Export` > `Plugin Development` > `Deployable
>   plug-ins and fragments`.

In other words, I just need to automate this process using Ant. Any idea how to proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can't really be done with Ant alone. You should use **[Tycho](https://eclipse.org/tycho/)** or [PDE Build](https://www.eclipse.org/pde/pde-build/) to build bundle (plug-in) JARs. Take note that Tycho is the modern, preferred option; I'm not sure that PDE Build is even actively maintained or used any more.

Comment: Yes I know it can be done using Tycho, but the installation process and usage of Maven and Tycho both for relatively small scale projects seem very complicated.

Comment: Maven is a trivial installation, and Tycho is just a plug-in for Maven (no installation). There is a bit of learning curve for Tycho, but I'm pretty sure you'll find the work necessary to do it's job is more than the work to learn Tycho.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate Ant scripts from the PDE tools by right-clicking on a relevant manifest file (e.g. plugin.xml) in the project and selecting **PDE Tools --> Create Ant Build File**.

[image]

[This link](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_feature_generating_ant.htm?cp=4_2_0_3) from the Eclipse Mars documentation explains in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You could try manually editing the build.xml, adding something like

```
<!-- This builds a .jar file, Assuming you have a set of .class files
     created by some "compile" target. -->
<target name="build" depends="compile">

    <!-- We need to set up class path for any required libraries so that we
         can add it to the manifest file later. -->
    <path id="build.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${lib.location}"/>
    </path>

    <!-- Now we convert the class path we just set up to a manifest class
         path - we'll call it manifest.cp. We also need to tell it where our 
         .jar file will be output. -->
    <manifestclasspath property="manifest.cp" jarfile="${jar.output.dir}/filename.jar">
        <!-- We just give it the classpath we set up previously. -->
        <classpath refid="build.classpath"/>
    </manifestclasspath>

    <!-- Now we can make the .jar. It needs to know the base directory of
         our compiled .class files. -->
    <jar destfile="${jar.target}/filename.jar" basedir="${class.target}">
        <!-- Set up the manifest file with the name of the main class and
             the manifest class path we set up earlier. -->
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="name of main class"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${manifest.cp}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>

</target>
```